# Подпоследовательности

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки

Дана `строка1` (или ряд чисел, это не так важно) и дана `строка2`, которая будет являться подпоследовательностью `строки1`.
Как можно реализовать следующее: убрать какое-то минимальное количество элементов из `строки1`, чтобы не получилось такой подпоследовательности?
Например для строки `abcdefacb` и подпоследовательности `acb` ответом будет `abcdefac`. Подпоследовательностью, простым языком, можно назвать какие-то элементы, в какой-то строке или каком-то ряде, при удалении между ними элементов образуется подстрока или подряд, или подмассив (последовательность). По сути, то же, но элементы не должны обязательно быть подряд идущими.

Comment: Объясните что такое "подпоследовательность", судя по вашим комментариям под удаленными ответами, порядок букв не имеет значения. Этого не описано в тексте вопроса. И если уж порядок не имеет значения, почему `abcdefac` является ответом, ведь ответ начинается на `abc` который есть просто перестановка букв удаляемого

Comment: И кстати, если нужен именно алгоритм решения, то почему в тегах жестко фиксирован язык ?

Comment: почему не abcdefcb или не abcdefab?

Comment: Croessmah, потому что тогда на позициях 0, 2 и 7 образуется подпоследовательность. Mike, как раз порядок - самое основное. Подпоследовательностью, простым языком, можно назвать какие-то элементы, в какой-то строке или каком-то ряде, при удалении между ними элементов образуется подстрока или подряд, или подмассив (последовательность). По сути, тот же подмассив, но элементы не должны обязательно стоять по порядку.

Comment: @S.Andrew Коментарии будут удалены, а вопрос останется, уточняйте все эти моменты _в тексте вопроса_

Comment: C++ в тегах, так как из всех языков знаю более-менее только C++, Python и Javascript. На питоне можно использовать много своих функций, которые будет трудно перестроить на C++, а решение в итоге необходимо переделывать под C++, что будет проблематично. Такая же ситуация и с JS.

Answer (score 0):

Эта задача решается с помощью динамического программирования.

Сначала "на пальцах". Пусть у нас строка 2 состоит из 2 символов `ab`. Тогда `a` мы в строке 1 должны убирать сначала (сколько нужно) а символы `b` с конца. При это последний убранный `a` будет *раньше* чем первый убранный `b` (очевидно). Можно уже начинать перебирать границу раздела, поддерживая число символов (за линейно).

Что делать, если строка длиннее. Для простоты понимания с конца. Пусть мы уже взяли предпоследний (`N-1`) символ строки 2 и он перешёл в `j` строки 1. Тогда мы должны удалить все последние (`N`) символы строки 1. Заполнили массив `F[N-1][j]`. Теперь пусть мы расставили `N-2` символов. Используя идею из упрощения с 2 символами мы можем перебрать точку оптимальности (выбрать отрезок `[j,k]` такой что число элементов равный `N` на нём плюс `F[N-1][k]` будет минимально). Так мы получили `F[N-2][j]`. Повторять N раз.

При правильной реализации сложности будет квадратичная. Если не получается за квадрат - пишите за куб.

P.S. я надеюсь оптимальнее по времени это решать нет необходимости (это возможно).

Answer (score 0):

Возможное решение, но нужно проверять на тестах:

Есть строка "21212122"  и подстрока "121"

Для начала посчитаем и запомним позиции вхождения подстроки. У нас есть 2 вхождения на позиции 1 и 3(отсчет от 0). Длинна подстроки 3(121).
Для каждого вхождения проверяем цепляем ли мы следующее вхождение.

1(вхождение) + 3(длинна подстроки) -1(отсчет от нуля) = 3 
 А 3 <= 3(следующие вхождение) Значит удаляем 3 символ. Иначе удаляем любой (допустим 1).
И так перебираем все вхождения.

Таким образом мы удалим минимальное количество символов из последовательности

---

Другой вариант перебором. Находим все вхождения. Идем циклом по вхождениям. Перебором удаляем по 1 символу, затем по 2, итд и проверяем как изменилась строка. В конце перебора удаляем наилучший вариант и идем к следующему вхождению